# How to check if cross-domain requests are disabled

Tags: php, ajax, security

I keep reading that to make ajax requests safe, I need to make sure that cross-site requests are disabled. On the server side, how exactly do I disable cross-site requests, or check if they are disabled/enabled?

Comment: Your question title says *cross domain* but your question body says *cross site*. Which one is it?

Comment: @alex is cross-domain different from cross-site? What I meant is that the ajax request was fired because the user did something while surfing my site (not because someone manually triggered the ajax call from a script they have elsewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross site requests are disabled by default..
fyi : take a look at same origin policy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I read that they are enabled if you have flash content. Not sure if they get enabled automatically or I have to enable a setting myself. But again how can I check for sure if they're enabled or disabled? Is there a test?

Comment: write a sample script, which belongs to your domain, try ajax-ing some url from google domain.. Fails right ? that means google servers have it disabled. Now create a virtual host or something in your server, i.e have 2 domains of your own, like domainA and domainB, try ajax from domainB to your site, if that fails, you are safe...

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain is *always* banned because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

As for your JavaScript making a XHR and someone spoofing one, they are the same and impossible to differentiate (though you can definitely make it harder).

Answer (score 0):

May be someone can open your page in hyperlink so please make sure that http referrer is always from your site.